# Why are there large gaps in the spoilers of the Airbus A300?

Tags: aircraft-design, spoilers, airbus-a300

The spoilers on the Airbus A300 have large gaps at the bottom:

[image: A300 wing]
<sup>(A300-600R, modified from [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:A300-600R_Spoilers_jp_001.jpg), original picture by Tennen-Gas, CC BY-SA 3.0)</sup>

I have never seen any other aircraft with such gaps in the spoilers. Airbus also got rid of them on the A310:

[image: A310 wing]
<sup>(A310-322, [ETH-Bibliothek Zürich](https://www.e-pics.ethz.ch/index/ethbib.bildarchiv/ETHBIB.Bildarchiv_LBS_SR04-000536_258961.html), picture by Swissair, CC BY-SA 4.0)</sup>

Since the point of spoilers is to disrupt airflow on the top of the wing to reduce lift, it seems counter-productive to include such gaps. So what is their purpose?

Comment: I cannot answer with scientific accuracy, but the gaps do not diminish the efficiency of the spoilers in a significant manner, but relative to their size the pitching moment and actuation force required are smaller compared to a "solid" version.

Comment: What do dive brakes have to do with it????

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Literature on the A300's spoilers is lacking, so is the flight manual's description. But based on publicly available information, there is a very strong candidate for a reason.*

---

The A310's wing is very different from the A300's. Of the relevant differences, the A300's wing is:

1. Thinner<sup>[1]</sup> (you can also visually tell: wing thickness under the deployed spoilers and spoiler thickness)
2. Outboard section having double-slotted flaps (not on the *later* model -600R shown in the question)<sup>[2]</sup>

> [image]
> Three different A300/A310 flaps,<sup>[2]</sup> and A300 v A310 wing thickness<sup>[1]</sup>

Both of which *when combined* would lead to a spoiler mechanism packaging difficulty, which leads to smaller spoiler actuators. The A300's spoiler with a gap would lessen the low pressure behind the spoiler, making it easier to deploy and hold.

**In fact,** the inboard spoilers where the wing is thick, the spoilers are normal:

> [image]
> — Lufthansa Airbus A300 Landing Berlin Tegel ([YouTube](https://youtu.be/2qhSFMl5vmU?t=333))

---

Another airliner with such a gap is the [Caravelle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sud_Aviation_Caravelle) VI-R. The gap is referred to as a **breather slot:**

> [Spoilers] require holding open as the airflow tends to blow them closed. Some [spoilers] feature breather slots, e.g. the ones of the Airbus A300 and Sud Aviation Caravelle.<sup>[3]</sup>

---

1: Airbus FAST magazine #5 ([PDF](https://www.airbus.com/content/dam/corporate-topics/publications/fast/FAST05.pdf))
2: Aerodynamic Design of Airbus High-lift Wings in a Multidisciplinary Environment ([PDF](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Daniel-Reckzeh/publication/242581172_AERODYNAMIC_DESIGN_OF_AIRBUS_HIGH-LIFT_WINGS_IN_A_MULTIDISCIPLINARY_ENVIRONMENT/links/5538ae9b0cf226723ab63670/AERODYNAMIC-DESIGN-OF-AIRBUS-HIGH-LIFT-WINGS-IN-A-MULTIDISCIPLINARY-ENVIRONMENT.pdf))
3: Alternative Air Brake Concepts for Transport Aircraft Steep Approach ([PDF](https://mediatum.ub.tum.de/doc/1086897/353905.pdf))

Comment: Beautiful answer, any idea why the A321 breaks with the flap-trend so obviously?

Comment: Thanks @ROIMaison / See p. 7 of the second ref. In short, Airbus favors high-lift wings w/ simple flaps, but since the A321 came after the 320 (a stretched variant), to avoid redesigning the landing gear and to achieve similar performance the flaps were made double-slotted. Not in the ref.: a similar thing happened w/ the 350 stretch (the -1000) where they had to redesign the aft part of the wing. Boeing on the other hand favors high-lift flaps, which doesn't require changing when stretching models. See [this post](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/43093/14897) for more.

Comment: Nice one. I even found a [photo](https://amp.reddit.com/r/aviation/comments/3nwj8x/sud_aviation_caravelle_landing_in_stockholm_with/) of the Caravelle with spoilers deployed.